# How compiler translates the lambda expressions in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

```
//Code 1

interface Demo {
    double myMeth();
}

class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Demo myDemo = () -> 98.6;
    }
}
```

What I want to know is that, How the compiler implement the statement?

> () -> 98.6;         //statement 1

The above statement is equivalent to

```
//Code 2

double myMeth() {
    return 98.6;
}
```

So, does the compiler replaces the `statement 1` by `code 2` during compilation

or the compiler do something else?

Comment: Read this article: http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-8-Lambdas-A-Peek-Under-the-Hood

Comment: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html

Comment: Try decompiling the classfile with `javap -c -v -p MyClass.class` and you can see for yourself!

Answer (score -1):

Semantically (though not implementationally), it is basically the same as

```
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Demo myDemo = new Demo() {
            public double myMeth() {
                return 98.6;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't actually translate a lambda expression to an anonymous class creation expression. Lambda expressions are implemented in a more efficient way.

Comment: Lambda expressions also have different semantics than inner class instances.  The meaning of names inside the body of lambdas is treated differently (no comb lookup); the identity semantics of a lambda expression is also different from that of an anonymous class creation expression.